# Log description in Event Viewer while logging PHP information logs on IIS

Tags: php, iis, logging

I have a PHP website hosted on an IIS 8 Server running on Windows Server 2012. I have PHP 5.3.28 installed. I want to log information messages in Event Viewer. I have tried the following code:

```
openlog('php', LOG_CONS | LOG_NDELAY | LOG_PID, LOG_USER | LOG_PERROR);
syslog(LOG_INFO, 'This is a message');
closelog();
```

I turned on **error_reporting** in **php.ini** and set **error_log=syslog**

The following is the entry in Event Viewer:

```
The description for Event ID 2 from source PHP-5.3.28 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

php[10052]
This is a message
```

I feel that there is some configuration required in php.ini, but I am not able to ascertain what it would be so that I can provide a generic description for that log message.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can download reg file from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/master/win32/syslog.reg)
change PHP-5.3.99-dev to your version for example PHP-5.7.0
change EventMessageFile value from g:\test\srctrunkinstall\php7ts.dll to

Answer (score 0):

Here's a registry file to import to register PHP as an event source (update the PHP version and DLL location in the appropriate places).

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\PHP-8.3.0]
"TypesSupported"=dword:00000007
"EventMessageFile"="D:\\php\\php8ts.dll"
```